# How to copy/paste content in React with document.execCommand?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to copy/paste a text when clicking on a button. I've read tutorials that only work with a text-area. How to do it with a button?

I know react-copy-to-clipboard exists, but I'd prefer to avoid any package.

Here is what I've done:

```js
import React, {useState, useRef} from "react"

export default function App() {
  const ref = useRef(null);

  const copyToClipboard = () => {
    ref.current.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
  };

  return (
    <div>
          <button 
          ref={ref} 
          value="hoowdy ho!" 
          onClick={copyToClipboard}>
          Copy
          </button> 

    </div>
  );
}
```

So when clicking on the button, the text "hoowdy ho!" should be copied. How to do it?

For now, I've got the error:

> ref.current.select is not a function

Comment: `.select()` only exists on inputs and textarea's. Do you have to copy the buttons text, or could you just have a hidden input with the same string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution was to hide an input, as suggested by DBS:

```js
import React, {useRef} from "react"

export default function App() {
  const ref = useRef(null);

  const copyToClipboard = () => {
    ref.current.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={copyToClipboard}>Copy</button> 
      <input ref={ref} 
       style={{opacity:0, pointerEvents:"none"}}
       value="hoowdy ho!"/>
    </div>
  );
}
```